# WhiteBox's Tools VectorStreamNetworkAnalysis direction of digitization issue

Tags: whitebox-tools

I used the VectorStreamNetworkAnalysis tool to order streams (Strahler Order), but it switched the direction of digitization for some, but not all streams.  The ones that were switched don't make sense, maybe because of the DEM I used.  I would like it to order the streams, but leave the digitization direction topology intact.

Comment: You had a tag for QGIS but make no mention of how it is relevant to your question in its body so I removed.

Comment: [RivEX](https://www.rivex.co.uk/html/info_attribution.html) can assign Strahler Order as well as Hack and Shreve to a vector network.